# Cannot start an activity properly from a Listview with Search option

Tags: android, listview, search, android-intent, android-activity

I have created an application that is supposed to show a listview with searchbox and items that user can click on and start a new activity, or search for the specific one and do the same.

Right now I can search for an item and start an activity that it is supposed to, but when I click without searching, it doesn't start properly. For example clicking on first 10 items launches only 1 same activity instead of the 10 different ones.

My code looks like this -

```
public class ItemMenu extends Activity {

private ListView lv;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

EditText inputSearch;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_menu);

    String items[] = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5",  "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10", "Item 11"  etc...
    };

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ItemListView);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_item);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_item, R.id.item_item_title, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_item_title);
            String sText = textview.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = null;
            if(sText.equals("Item 1"))
               intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B1.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 2"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B2.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 3"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B3.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 4"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B4.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 5"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B5.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 6"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B6.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 7"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B7.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 8"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B8.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 9"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B9.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 10"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B10.class);
            else if(sText.equals("Item 11"))
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        B11.class);

            etc...


            if(intent != null)
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            ItemMenu.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });





}
```

}

When I click on an Item LogCat shows this:

```
    W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
    W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
    D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9   budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*--:af(
    D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
    I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
    D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
    I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is about this line because It finds the view `item_item_title` in your layout:

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_item_title);
```

But you are trying the find item's view that is clicked. So you should use:

```
TextView textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_item_title);
```